# Java library to manipulate jar files

Tags: java, jar

Can anyone recommend a Java library to manipulate **jar** files? I am finding the facilities available at **java.util.jar** rather terse (or maybe I don't have some example code to look at). I am interested in things like:

1. adding files to a **jar**
2. removing files from a **jar**
3. create a **jar** file from a folder
4. deflate a **jar** file to a folder
5. reading the contents of a **jar entry** (perhaps in memory, without having to deflate the **jar** on disk)
6. creating a **jar entry** in memory without having to read from a file on disk.
7. asking whether a **jar** file entry is a **Manifest** file or some other special file or not.

If anyone can point to example code using either the **java.util.jar** or some other library that would help. In particular looking at the classes and methods of **java.util.jar** it is not clear to me how to read the contents of a particular Jar entry or even how to deflate the **jar** (without spawning an external process).

Comment: I'm not sure what specifically you're looking for. Determining the entry "type" is a matter of either (a) checking the file name, or (b) checking the actual contents.

Comment: i smell hacking (code injection) ;)

Comment: @Dave: correct. But maybe a library could provide (b). And that's only item 7.

Comment: @MenelaosPerdikeas All the rest seem pretty straight-forward, not sure what the issue(s) are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1 & 2 are simple manual operations of copying the entries from Jar to another adding or leaving the entries you want, deleting he original file and renaming the new to replace it.

As jtahlbom has pointed out, the Java Jar API handles the rest out of the box.

**UPDATE with example**

These are REALLY basic examples.  They show you how to read and write a Jar.  Basically from that you can derive just about everything else you need to do.

I've setup a personal library (not included) which basically allows me to pass in an `InputStream` and have it written to an `OutputStream` and visa versa.  This means you could read from any where and write to anywhere, which could cover most of you requirements.

```
public void unjar(File jar, File outputPath) throws IOException {
    JarFile jarFile = null;
    try {
        if (outputPath.exits() || outputPathFile.mkdirs()) {
            jarFile = new JarFile(jar);
            Enumeration<JarEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                JarEntry entry = entries.nextElement();
                File path = new File(outputPath + File.separator + entry.getName());
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    if (!path.exists() && !path.mkdirs()) {
                        throw new IOException("Failed to create output path " + path);
                    }
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Extracting " + path);

                    InputStream is = null;
                    OutputStream os = null;
                    try {
                        is = jarFile.getInputStream(entry);
                        os = new FileOutputStream(path);

                        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRead = -1;
                        while ((bytesRead = is.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {
                            os.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                        }
                        os.flush();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            os.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                        try {
                            is.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            throw IOException("Output path does not exist/could not be created");
        }
    } finally {
        try {
            jarFile.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}

public void jar(File jar, File sourcePath) throws IOException {
    JarOutputStream jos = null;
    try {
        jos = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(jar));

        List<File> fileList = getFiles(sourcePath);
        System.out.println("Jaring " + fileList.size() + " files");

        List<String> lstPaths = new ArrayList<String>(25);
        for (File file : fileList) {
            String path = file.getParent().replace("\\", "/");
            String name = file.getName();

            path = path.substring(sourcePath.getPath().length());
            if (path.startsWith("/")) {
                path = path.substring(1);
            }

            if (path.length() > 0) {
                path += "/";
                if (!lstPaths.contains(path)) {
                    JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(path);
                    jos.putNextEntry(entry);
                    jos.closeEntry();
                    lstPaths.add(path);
                }
            }

            System.out.println("Adding " + path + name);

            JarEntry entry = new JarEntry(path + name);
            jos.putNextEntry(entry);

            FileInputStream fis = null;
            try {
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead = -1;
                while ((bytesRead = fis.read(byteBuffer)) != -1) {
                    jos.write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }
                jos.flush();
            } finally {
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
            jos.closeEntry();
        }
        jos.flush();
    } finally {
        try {
            jos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

If you take the time look, there are a number of examples of how to add/remove entries from the from zip/jar files on SO

Answer (score 2):

A jar is just a [zip file with a different extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_%28file_format%29) (and a manifest), so you might as well be interested by zip libraries like [zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/) or [java.util.zip](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-frame.html).

Answer (score 1):

[TrueZip](http://truezip.java.net/) seems like a pretty comprehensive zip library.

Btw, i'm pretty sure the jdk jar API can handle 3-7 pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Apache Commons Compress](http://commons.apache.org/compress/) can help you here.