# delete/add files to/from jar inside jar

Tags: ant, jar, addition, delete-file

basically I want to delete files from and add files to a jar file which happens to be inside another jar file. Is this possible without completely extracting the jar files and repacking them again?

Would be great, if there is an ant script for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java library to manipulate jar files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164889/java-library-to-manipulate-jar-files)

Answer (score 0):

`Is this possible without completely extracting the jar files and repacking them again?`

```
- for addition / updation : Yes
- for deletion : NO. 
  however, instead of using the manual option, there's an alternative:
     <zip>
       <zipfileset/>
     </zip> 
     <move/>
```

---

```
parent.jar 
 |__child.jar
 |   |
 |   |__some files..
 |
 |__some files..
```

*addition/deletion to be performed on* `child.jar`

for **any** operation on `child.jar`, it will have to be extracted from `parent.jar`, without exception:

```
<unjar src="..\abc\parent.jar" dest="..\abc\temp">
    <patternset includes="child.jar"/>
</unjar>
```

**addition/deletion on`child.jar`:**

--> to *add/update* files in `..\temp\child.jar` from a ***basedir - temp2***.

```
<zip destfile="..\abc\temp\child.jar" basedir="..\xyz\temp2" update="true"/>
```

`update="true"` adds new files and overwrites the ones that are already present within     the **`destfile`**.

--> to *delete* files from `..abc\temp\child.jar`:

```
<zip destfile="..\abc\temp\temp_child.jar">
    <zipfileset src="..\abc\temp\child.jar" excludes="files_to_be_deleted" />
</zip>                  
<move file="..\abc\temp\temp_child.jar" toFile="..\abc\temp\child.jar"/>
```

the modified `child.jar` can easily be updated into `parent.jar`: (same as adding/updating files on `child.jar`)

```
<zip destfile="..\abc\parent.jar" basedir="..\abc\temp" update="true"/>
```